# Change the size of pictures in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a portfolio for a web site here is the code. I want to make the pictures look smaller and to also take the full width just like in the example. But I like them to look more like a square. I tried manipulating with height but than it wouldn't show all the picture it would crop the picture and I don't want these pictures to be cropped when they are made smaller.

Thanks in advance!

```css
.cards{
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding-right: 5rem;
  padding-left: 5rem;
  padding-top: 135px;
  padding-bottom: 135px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 cards" style="background-image: url(https://xubuntu.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/f51c/IMG_3397_2560x1600-web.jpg);"></div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cards " style="background-image: url(https://xubuntu.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/469a/pesseguinho-web.jpg);"></div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cards" style="background-image: url(https://xubuntu.org/wpcontent/uploads/2018/04/8fbb/40103442821_db033c72a4_o-web.jpg);"></div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cards" style="background-image: url(https://xubuntu.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/3ed0/2017_07_21_23_33_13_03-web.jpg);"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 cards" style="background-image: url(https://xubuntu.org/wpcontent/uploads/2018/04/e68e/Winter_Wonderland_by_Sarah_Muenz-web.jpg);"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 cards" style="background-image: url(https://xubuntu.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/c099/EastHarbourSunrise-web.jpg);"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 cards" style="background-image: url(https://xubuntu.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/f51c/IMG_3397_2560x1600-web.jpg);"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Also if u can think of any other way without using bootstrap let me now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the class's in bootstrap for images and not background images.

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

img-fluid will stretch 100% of width